# I am not able to use RemBg Python Software. Help me

Tags: python, django, image

I was using RemBg Software provided in this [Repository](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg). Whenever I used it. It gives me the following error-

```
Failed to import ahead-of-time-compiled modules.
This is expected on first import.
Compiling modules and trying again.
This might take a minute.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pymatting_aot\cc.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pymatting_aot.aot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatting_aot.aot'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\Scripts\rembg-server.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\rembg\cmd\server.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ..bg import remove
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\rembg\bg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pymatting.alpha.estimate_alpha_cf import estimate_alpha_cf
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pymatting\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pymatting_aot.cc
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pymatting_aot\cc.py", line 54, in <module>
    compile_modules()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pymatting_aot\cc.py", line 8, in compile_modules
    cc = CC("aot")
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\numba\pycc\cc.py", line 65, in __init__
    self._toolchain = Toolchain()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\numba\pycc\platform.py", line 78, in __init__
    self._raise_external_compiler_error()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\numba\pycc\platform.py", line 121, in _raise_external_compiler_error
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Attempted to compile AOT function without the compiler used by `numpy.distutils` present. Cannot find suitable msvc.
```

I also tried to start their server by using the rembg-server command but it still not works.
Can anybody help me?

Update - Sorry for my behavior. I have installed C++ Build tools. But now when I run their "rembg-server" command it takes too much time to run almost 15 to 25 mins. and After the time it shows this error -

```
ERROR:rembg.cmd.server:Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\rembg\cmd\server.py", line 31, in index
    file_content = urlopen(unquote_plus(url)).read()
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1375, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "c:\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "c:\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1264, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "c:\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1098, in putrequest
    self._validate_path(url)
  File "c:\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1198, in _validate_path
    raise InvalidURL(f"URL can't contain control characters. {url!r} "
http.client.InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '///C:/Users/nutan/Downloads/app anime icon [Music].jpeg' (found at least ' ')
ERROR:rembg.cmd.server:Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "c:\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "c:\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "c:\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "c:\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "c:\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "c:\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 919, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "c:\python39\lib\socket.py", line 822, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "c:\python39\lib\socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\rembg\cmd\server.py", line 31, in index
    file_content = urlopen(unquote_plus(url)).read()
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1375, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
ERROR:rembg.cmd.server:Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\rembg\cmd\server.py", line 31, in index
    file_content = urlopen(unquote_plus(url)).read()
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 514, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1270, in do_request_
    raise URLError('no host given')
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

Edit - How can I use it using code. I wrote this code. Which is provided in their GitHub page. See the code and I am pasting the error below the code-

```
from rembg.bg import remove
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image

input_path = './Images/IMG3.jpeg'
output_path = './Images/out3.jpeg'

f = np.fromfile(input_path)
result = remove(f)
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(result)).convert("RGBA")
img.save(output_path)
```

Error message -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nutan\OneDrive\Desktop\Desktop\Locker\Image and Video Background Removal API and program\program\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    result = remove(f)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rembg\bg.py", line 91, in remove
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data)).convert("RGB")
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 904, in convert
    self.load()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 249, in load
    raise OSError(
OSError: image file is truncated (3 bytes not processed)
```

please fix these error above.

If somebody knows how to fix this please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The error message says it can't find MSVC. That is the Microsoft Visual C/C++ compiler. Do you have it installed?

Comment: I installed it and after that it is giving different error please help.

Comment: *A different error.* You are asking us to guess *what* error. If you don't say what is wrong we can't possibly suggest how to fix it. Edit your question to include the full error message. Don't put the info in a comment. It's impossible to read that way.

Comment: I am sorry for my behavior. Now I have updated the question. Please answer. Again sorry for my behavior.

Comment: The later error messages imply you're trying to pass a local file path to the rembg server. According to the [instructions](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg#usage-as-a-cli), you should use `rembg -o output.png input.png` to work with a local file.

Comment: And Can you please tell me how to make the rembg-server command work?

Comment: Thank you AKX I can now use it using cli but can you please tell me how to use it's server command "rembg-server"?

Comment: and please tell me this too. That how to completely  remove the background. After running the command it is returning the image with white background.

Comment: This line: `f = np.fromfile(input_path)` is expecting to read a saved numpy array of floating-point numbers. I am pretty sure it is not sensible to pass it an image file and expect it to do something useful.

Answer (score 2):

### easiest solution for windows

download python 3.10 from
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.1/python-3.11.1-embed-arm64.zip

place content of the folder in this folder

C:\Users\youusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\

tree should be like the image

[image]

createnew virtual env with this python3.10 by this commands

```
virtualenv myenv --python==python3.10 

myenv/scripts/activate

pip install rembg
```

that's all
for linux just move python content to other path --don't know where to be honest

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when install `rembg 1.0.27` latest version. Later on, I have installed the previous version of rembg. and issues are resolved. you can try the older version of rembg. I have installed the `1.0.10` version and its working for me.

```
pip install rembg==1.0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this after imports packages

```
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

Your problem will solved.

Comment: Your solution is not clear. Kindly elaboratee a bit more..